# Adding a new non-nullable column to a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ddl

I have a table for an event, and I have just made a new table for ticketing_information. Each event in the event table should have a ticketing_information, referenced by a unique id. I'm new to sql, so forgive me if this is a very basic/repeated question, but how should I go about making the migration add a new row to the ticketing_information table for every existing event, and giving the event the generated ticketing_information id?

If it helps, some of my sql is attached:

```
CREATE TABLE `ticketing_information` (
  `id` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tickets_available` BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE NOT NULL,
  `ticketing_url` VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_info_url` VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`);)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8; 

ALTER TABLE event
ADD COLUMN ticketing_information_id Int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL;
```

(This is a very stripped-down version of the code, but it should help illustrate the behavior I want)

I was thinking it should be something along the lines of

```
UPDATE event SET
ticketing_information_id = SELECT `id` FROM `ticketing_information` WHERE <some way of making a new ticketing_information?>;
```

But I don't really know what I'm doing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how i would perform something like, adding a new non-nullable column to an existing table, would be:

- adding that column in first step as nullable, otherwise you will not get the rdbms to modify the table, because it will violate the not null constraint.
- updating the new column to the data you want it to have

  ```
  UPDATE event e 
  SET e.ticketing_information_id = (SELECT `id` FROM `ticketing_information` WHERE id = e.id)
  ```

  Your update needs to tell the inner select, which row it is currently updating, so you are able to filter only the data of that particular row in the inner select.
- modifying the column to be not null

Comment: Couldn't you just do `UPDATE event SET ticketing_information_id = id`? not that it matters..

Comment: Those aren't the same tables. One is 'event' and the other 'ticketing_information'. If i understood correct by the information of the OP. It was just a guess that the inner select could be linked by id with the update statement. It should only show how to do something like this, how this will be implemented in the end i can't tell, i don't know the relations.

Comment: Sorry I did not read your query properly.. to be honest I just got a little worried that there was some reason i didn't know about for using this technique when it relates to one table only ;) thanks

Comment: if you only want to update one field with the content of another field in the same table you can do it like you suggested.

Comment: 1. there was no word lost about making the column not null, or did I miss it? 2. Even if it was, one would solve this using default values. 3. A nicer to read and maybe faster query (if your query doesn't internally get optimized to following syntax anyway): `update event e inner join ticketing_information t on e.whatever = t.whatever set e.whatever = t.whatever`

Comment: ehm, have you looked at the title of this question? :) I'm not quite sure if inner joins will work in update statements on every system. maybe im wrong and i have something in mind which is confusing me, but i think i had problems with inner joins in update statement, like you mentioned, under Oracle.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The question is for MySQL. Apart from that. The syntax I suggested is standard SQL.

Comment: the tags changed then, they had been sql before...
- ok, as i said, i was not quite sure with that inner join thing in updates